# Locally convertig HTML to PDF with playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I've got an spring boot application which uses [wkthmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert a HTML-file, which is generated during runtime by thymeleaf template engine, to PDF.

```java
String html = templateEngine.process("template.html", webCtx); // html file generated from template engine

Pdf pdf = new Pdf(wrapperConfig);
pdf.addPageFromString(html); // attach html template to parser
byte[] result = pdf.getPDF(); // parse html and return pdf
```

Meanwhile the library is deprecated and I'm looking for a successor. [Playwright seems to fit](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-pdf). However, playwrights is acting like a browser (call website, parse it and generate pdf), so i cannot "pass" the HTML from my template engine into it.

```java
try(Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
    Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch();
    Page page = browser.newPage();

    var url = "/some/website";
    page.navigate(url); // call browser
    page.emulateMedia(new Page.EmulateMediaOptions().setMedia(Media.SCREEN));

    result = page.pdf(); // parse website and return pdf
}
```

**I need a way to parse the html file from my template engine and let playwright render it as pdf**.

The **simplest solution i can image** is to return the html template with a web controller and navigate via playwright to this url. However, I need to handle authentication which seems a little bit overkill for this usecase.

Now I'm asking myself **if there is an easier solution**? Maybe something like temporary storing the html file in file system and access it via playwright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There certainly is. You can use [page.setContent](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-content) to assign the html markup to the page. Then you can use [page.pdf](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-pdf), or anything else you would normally be able to use on a live page.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!